# Managment of a Hyper-V server remotely

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Windows 7 machine, which I would like to use to manage Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. A while ago there was a reference to [Hyper V Manager MMC](http://blogs.technet.com/virtualization/archive/2008/03/25/hyper-v-manager-mmc-now-available.aspx) on the Windows Visualization blog, but the links are now dead.

Can this be done?

Billy3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the link you need:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en

It's call the Remove Server Administration Tool kit.

Download that and install it and you'll be able to manage a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine from a client machine.  This includes Hyper-V, as well as a lot of other stuff.